# Error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting this error, I'm not sure what I should do, I've tried to delete parameters and then it works, but I need it to work with parameters. The class "Manager" that inherits from "Employee" gives an error.

```
using System;

class MainClass
{
    class Employee
    {
        public string name;
        public string jobTitle;
        public double salary;

        public Employee(string empName, string empJobTitle, double empSalary)
        {
            

        }

        public double calculateYearlySalary(double salary)
        {
            double yearlySalary = salary * 12;

            return yearlySalary;
        }

    }

    class Manager : Employee
    {
        public int bonus;

        public Manager(string empName, string empJobTitle, double empSalary, int empBonus)
        {

        }

    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Employee emp1 = new Employee("John", "Junior Software Engineer", 32.45);
        Manager emp2 = new Manager("David", "Senior Software Engineer", 62.20, 10);

        Console.WriteLine(emp1.calculateYearlySalary(100.00));
    }

}
```

The error exactly:

> "/Users/Oliver/Projects/printstars/printstars/Program.cs(16,16): Error
> CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required
> formal parameter 'empName' of 'MainClass.Employee.Employee(string,
> string, double)' (CS7036) (printstars)"

Answer (score 22):

`Employee` has no parameterless constructor, so anything which inherits from it needs to specify the values to send to its constructor.  You can do this with constructor chaining:

```
public Manager(string empName, string empJobTitle, double empSalary, int empBonus)
    : base(empName, empJobTitle, empSalary)
    {

    }
```

The call to `base` tells the `Manager` constructor that it should pass those three parameters along to the `Employee` constructor when creating an instance of itself.

(Side note: You *probably* also meant to set your class fields within your constructors.  Otherwise those values are just going to be ignored.)

Comment: Thanks for the help, and yes, I was planning to set them but wanted to get rid of this error first.

Comment: So does this mean that any constructor from a derived class need to use call a constructor from its base first, so if you don't specify which one to use with chaining then it tried the use the parameterless one by default, which in this case doesn't exist hence the error?

Comment: @TheBoxyBear: Basically, yes.  To build any class you need to call a constructor, and since an inherited class is still an instance of its base class then that rule still applies.